# SQL Server: efficiently search for many values on many to many columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a website using SQL Server. In the admin interface, I have two fields:

- Subject: Math, English, History, ...
- Grade: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Multiple values of a field can be assigned to a record.

Now in the frontend search, I would like a visitor to be able to select more than one value of a field for search. For example, someone may search for Subject being Math OR History and Grade being 1 OR 3.

What table design and SQL statement (or MS-proprietary statement) should I use to have efficient search?

Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all input!

I feel compelled to explain. I am technical and familiar with SQL. One thing I learned over my MANY years of programming experience is to be practical. For this question, I already have an initial design, but not sure how other folks to handle it for **EFFICIENT SEARCH** (there are always smarter folks out there). Here is my table design for storing a record:

```
Subject
type: varchar. record example: ,1,3, (each is the id of corresponding value)

Grade (this means applicable grade)
type: varchar. record example: ,1,2, (each is the id of corresponding values. this means a record is applicable to grade 1, 2)
```

Search example

```
where (subject LIKE  '%,1,%' OR subject like '%,3,%') AND (grade like '%,1,%')
```

This design should lead to efficient search, but has drawbacks that it increases the complexity data management in the backend.

Another reason for my design is: the Subject and Grade each have a list of values that never/rarely change, and once a record is created, it never or rarely updates.

I am trying to strike a balance among simplicity, understandability, design, management, etc.

Comment: One row per subject/grade, never store comma separated values in one column.

Comment: The WROX book on database design is excellent.

Comment: "multiple values can be assigned to a record"? So your grade field could be `1`, and another record would have `1,3,5`? That's a bad design. it should be properly normalized.

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: You need to read up about normalization. It seems as though you are not even compliant with 1NF here.

Comment: If you really need multiple values for a field, then MS SQL server is not a good choice. You might instead use postgreSQL for example. It supports array datatype and built-in functions to deal with arrays.

Comment: This where clause `where (subject LIKE  '%,1,%' OR subject like '%,3,%') AND (grade like '%,1,%')` is not what I would call efficient.  Putting a "%" on the left side of a value automatically causes a full scan, which could be a table scan or an index scan.  Either way it isn't good.

Comment: ewahner, what is the applicable and efficient way of search in case of my design? want to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

```
create table Subject (
    SubjectId int identity(1, 1),
    SubjectName nvarchar(255),
    other fields.... )

create table GradingScale (
    GradeId int identity(1, 1),
    Grade int,
    Description varchar(25),
    other fields... )

create table Students (
    StudentId int identity(1, 1),
    StudentName nvarchar(255))

create table StudentGrades (
    StudentId int,
    SubjectId int,
    GradeId int,
    SemesterId int )

create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnArray] ( @Str varchar(max), @Delim varchar(1) = ' ', @RemoveDups bit = 0 )
returns  @tmpTable table ( arrValue varchar(max))
as
begin
   declare @pos integer
   declare @lastpos integer
   declare @arrdata varchar(8000)
   declare @data varchar(max)

   set @arrdata = replace(@Str,@Delim,'|')
   set @arrdata = @arrdata + '|'
   set @lastpos = 1
   set @pos = 0
   set @pos = charindex('|', @arrdata)
   while @pos <= len(@arrdata) and @pos <> 0
   begin
      set @data = substring(@arrdata, @lastpos, (@pos - @lastpos))
      if rtrim(ltrim(@data)) > ''
      begin
         if @RemoveDups = 0
         begin          
            insert into @tmpTable ( arrValue ) values ( @data )
         end
         else
         begin
             if not exists( select top 1 arrValue from @tmpTable where arrValue = @data ) 
             begin   
                insert into @tmpTable ( arrValue ) values ( @data )
             end
        end
      end
      set @lastpos = @pos + 1
      set @pos = charindex('|', @arrdata, @lastpos)
   end
   return 
end

select *
  from Students st
 inner join StudentGrades sg on sg.StudentId = st.StudentId
 inner join Subject s on sg.SubjectId = s.SubjectId
 inner join GradingScale gs on sg.GradeId = gs.GradeId
 inner join dbo.fnArray(@subjects, ',') sArr on s.SubjectId = convert(int, sArr.arrValue)
 inner join dbo.fnArray(@grades, ',') gArr on gs.GradeId = convert(int, gArr.arrValue)
```

obviously @subjectId and @gradeId could be passed in via some drop down selectors or however your UI is composed.

Edited to use dbo.fnArray, a little tool that can parse delimited strings into a list.

Now of course this would mean that if you had 2 subjects and 2 grades...like Show me all students that took ( Math and Science ) and scored ( 2 or 3 ) this would work.  However if you wanted students who took Math and scored 2 or 3 or Students who took Science and scored a 3 you would have to rework the query.

Comment: ewahner, thanks for showing me the code! Is your code able to handle search for multiple values of subjects or grades at the same time?

Comment: Updated with a more advanced method.

Comment: Thanks for code update! Honestly, you are obviously one of MSSQL genius I admire. I voted up your answer and all your replies.  As I indicated in the post, the available values for Subject and Grades are more than just two. Another thing I want to avoid is stored procedure and the complexity shown in your code.

Comment: ewahner, another question if I may. Based on your experience and considering that the available values for Subject and Grade are more than just two, which search is more efficient? Your way and my way? I can see you are so experienced in myssql.

Comment: Don't let complexity lead you to believe that it is less efficient.  By utilizing a normalized methodology like the one I have proposed, your overall database size should remain much smaller than if you had a more flattened approach.  I have written search queries that search a database of over 500 Million records with multiple requirements, including aggregates and keeping with a normalized schema has made it efficient as well as maintainable.

Comment: ewahner, thanks so much for your follow-up. I will look at your code more carefully to see whether it works for me. I will select your post as the answer if it can. Thanks, again!!